# When i click save and send test email it's redirecting to frontend

Tags: admin, redirect

When i click save and send test email it's redirecting to

```
frontendbaseurl/awfollowupemail_rules/edit/id/16/tab/followupemail_tabs_sendtest/key/f58025911cd3cb18f5d6683ab609c608/
```

but need to redirect to

```
adminurl/awfollowupemail_rules/edit/id/16/tab/followupemail_tabs_sendtest/key/f58025911cd3cb18f5d6683ab609c608/
```

redirect line

```
$this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $model->getId(), 'tab' => $sendTest ? $sendTest : $tab));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your redirect line is in a template file (.phtml) or in controller ?

If it is in a controller, can you verify you reach correctly your controller ?

If it is from a template file, you have to check if there is a formkey eg : `<div><?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?></div>`

Magento will check each times your formkey to prevent security issue